# Kendo UI Datasource and Arrays

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I am sending over a series of array values from a posted form to an MVC3 Controller. I was hoping the default modelbinder would be able to parse this but I'm having some difficulty with it.

The array is in the following format:

```
order[0].[type]=some value.
```

I think this is the reason the model binder is not parsing my values because I'm not getting anything populated in my model.

What would be another way to handle this?

Comment: I am having this exact same problem. Have you come to any solution?

Comment: I was having the same issue and I solved it like this: I POST my data using a JSON format to the controller. The controller accepts a string parameter, which I then de-serialize into a strongly typed object using the JavaScriptSerializer(). var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            try
            {
                var invoice = serializer.Deserialize<Invoice>(Invoice);
            }

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to post more of your code so I can see what you are doing exactly. However saying this you need to pass the model to the view/partial view on the response you are trying to retrieve on the post request.

If not you will have to iterate through the Form Collection that will be returned and the Actions Methods type e.g. ActionMethodName(FormCollection form), one issue is name versus id its the name of the Kendo UI control that is used to get the value not the id.

Answer (score 0):

1As far as I remember the right format was:

```
orders[0].OrderID=13;
orders[0].Name="test";
orders[1].OrderID=15;
orders[1].Name="again test";
```

The indexing should start from 0 and increase by 1.

Check this out: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx